# If key in dictionary returning false when key exists

Tags: python, if-statement, semantics

Python 3.2

This might be really stupid but:

```
items = {'1': 'ACK', '2': 'RELQ', '3': 'COM'}
choice = input('Choose an option:\n1.ACK\n2.RELQ\n3.COM\n')
print(choice)
if choice in items:
    print(choice)
    option = items[choice]
else:
    print('Input not recognized')
```

If you type 1 it keeps returning

```
1
Input not recognized
```

The `choice in items` is returning a false?

This should be really easy but I just cant see what it is.

UPDATE:

```
print(type(choice))` returns str

print(len(choice)) returns 2

print(repr(choice)) returns '1\r'
print(choice[0]) returns 1
```

The input was receiving a \r newline character with the input()

Comment: This bit of code works for me, running windows 8 64 bit python 3.4(.1) with IDLE.

Comment: Well it doesn't work for me at all. I even checked the type using `print(type(choice))` and it returns str.

Comment: Check `len(choice)`.  It's possible it's grabbing an extra char somewhere

Comment: I meant, what differences to my run setup that you're using. I know string comparison can get shakey on Mac's due to `\r` instead of `\n` usage

Comment: Nice catch, `print(len(choice))` returns `2` where is it grabbing this extra char?

Comment: @Matthew windows 8 x64 with x86 python 3.2.5

Comment: Probably it grabs the newline character, so in order for your code to work you should trim the choices variable. Alternatively if your dict keys would be ints instead of strings, you could just perform casting operation.

Comment: @LCGA `print(list(map(ord, choice)))`, let's see what we're looking at

Comment: can you try `print(repr(choice))` ?

Comment: Try `print(choice[0])` and `print(choice[1])`, there might be a space and/or newline character in it, it's not an OS difference I had suspected.

Comment: @roadRich `print(list(map(ord, choice)))` == `[49, 13]`
@darkpotpot `print(repr(choice))` == `'1\r'`
@Matthew `print(choice[0])` == `1`
`print(choice[1])` == `` `#newline ?`

Comment: `chr(13)` is `\r`, carriage return, sounds like an OS missmatch somewhere?  What OS are you on, and what is the value of `os.linesep`?

Comment: @roadRich `print(list(map(ord, choice)))` == `[49, 13]`

@darkpotpot `print(repr(choice))` == `'1\r'`

@Matthew `print(choice[0])` == `1`


`print(choice[1])` == `` `#newline ?`

@RoadieRich windows 8 x64 with x86 python 3.2.5

`>>> import os`

`>>> os.linesep`

`'\r\n'`

Comment: @RoadieRich, @LCGA, @darkpotpot, @Matthew: Do you guys know why Python would not remove `\r` in Windows? this seem impractical, and I can't fathom where this could be wanted.

Comment: Thanks guys. and @EOL I have no idea why. Curios to hear.

Comment: I found out: this is a bug specific to 3.2.0: https://bugs.python.org/issue11272#msg136854. I included this information in my answer.

Comment: @EOL There is a [known bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue11272) on windows in python 3.2, but since you're using 3.2.5 you shouldn't be impacted.

Comment: @darpoptpot: Yeah, that's the bug that I quoted just above your comment. Good point, about 3.2.5 being used: I am not sure what's going there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably it grabs the newline character, so in order for your code to work you should trim the choices variable. Alternatively if your dict keys would be ints instead of strings, you could just perform casting operation.

EDIT:
your last comment proves my point because of the [49, 13] numbers - 13 is the ascii code for carriage return.

Just add:

```
choice = choice.strip()
```

Before the `if choice in items:`

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing a [bug in Python 3.2.0, fixed in 3.2.1](https://bugs.python.org/issue11272#msg136854): `input()` should not give you any trailing carriage return/newline character. I encourage you to upgrade Python, if you can.

I you are stuck with Python 3.2.0, you must either remove the trailing `\r` character:

```
import os
choice = input(…).rstrip(os.linesep)  # Robust (no assumption)
```

or use integers throughout:

```
items = {1: …}
choice = int(input(…))
```

This second choice is more natural, I would say, in your case, but it does not work if you also want to add letters as choices.

PS: Łukasz R.'s answer is good, too: it gives the added bonus of trimming whitespaces (trailing spaces,…).

Answer (score 2):

You are grabbing extra white-space characters (either \n or \r). After getting input simply use:

```
choice = choice.strip()
```

As a result your string would be trimmed from both sides. If starting whitespace characters matters use:

```
choice = choice.rstrip()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of solving this is by converting the input return value into string, since the keys in your `items` dictionary are strings, like this:

```
items = {'1': 'ACK', '2': 'RELQ', '3': 'COM'}
choice = input('Choose an option:\n1.ACK\n2.RELQ\n3.COM\n')
choice = str(choice)
print(choice)
if choice in items:
    print(choice)
    option = items[choice]
else:
    print('Input not recognized')
```

You can also make life easier for you, if you don't care about the type of your dictionary' Keys (whether string, integer...etc), you can simply define them as integers rather than strings, like this:

```
items = {1: 'ACK', 2: 'RELQ', 3: 'COM'}
choice = input('Choose an option:\n1.ACK\n2.RELQ\n3.COM\n')
print(choice)
if choice in items:
    print(choice)
    option = items[choice]
else:
    print('Input not recognized')
```

Like this you don't need to string any extra character and you save yourself extra coding.